# My apache server blocks PUT and DELETE requests and I have no idea why

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, http

First of all: yes I have checked previous questions. None of the solutions help.

So, my server blocks every PUT and DELETE request. I have searched everywhere but I didn't find a reason.

This is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /~user/api
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
</IfModule>
```

If I check the error logs, it clearly says that there was an authorisation error. "client denied by server configuration"

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Damnit StackOverflow, my question is totally different. Only PUT and DELETE requests are forbidden, rest is allowed. Nothing to do with authorized users.

Comment: check error logs.

Comment: Found it! I'll edit my question.

Comment: instead of PUT Delete, use simple POST and delete through php